# Weird MySQL syntax error: In a code which used to work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm encountering a syntax error in SQL and I tried everything, but can't find out what's wrong with the code.

```
$register_user = "INSERT INTO '".$this->users_table."' ( '".$this->username_collumn."', '".$this->email_collumn."','".$this->password_collumn."' ) VALUES ( '".$username."','".$email."','".$password."')";
```

All the variables are escaped, I also tried to use mysql_real_escape_string function, but it didn't help in any way. It seems like email is making problem, because in error report it's not displayed completely with the @ sign, but I can't figure out why.

The error is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''profiles' ( 'username', 'email', 'password' ) VALUES ( 'Corten', 'attrac' at line 1

I tried to escape variables in many ways, none of them solved the error. How can I solve this?

Comment: If you like Fluffeh's answer please accept it! Read more here please: meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235/195067

Answer (score 2):

Don't use single quotes around column or table names, use backticks instead:

```
$register_user = "INSERT INTO 
`".$this->users_table."` 
( `".$this->username_collumn."`, `".$this->email_collumn."`,`".$this->password_collumn."` ) 
VALUES ( '".$username."','".$email."','".$password."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Remove all the single quote from the table name and the columns

```
$register_user = "INSERT INTO ".$this->users_table." ( ".$this->username_collumn.", ".$this->email_collumn.",".$this->password_collumn.") VALUES ( '".$username."','".$email."','".$password."')";
```